# How to assign different member function pointers to different instances of registering classes?

Tags: c++, c++03, pointer-to-member

EDIT: I am limited to C++03 on this topic.

In the following code, class `Impl` derives from `Intf` and contains an instance of class `Caller`.

`Caller`'s ctor takes an `Intf::` instance and member function pointer; it invokes the latter on the former in `Caller::func()`.

`Impl`'s ctor registers itself and its member function `func()` with its contained `Caller` instance.

I would like for `Impl` to contain multiple `Caller` instances and register different member function pointers with each instance so that invoking each contained `Caller` instance's `::func()` results in a different `Impl` member function being called - can this be done?

The only way I could think to do this is to define multiple pure virtual functions in `Intf`, implement them in `Impl` and register those overriding functions. But this is not an ideal solution to me: I would like to know if there's a way to register different member function pointers with different instances of a registering class without creating virtual functions in the interface class 1:1 with overriding functions in the implementing class.

I need to exclude the possibility of `Caller` taking an `Impl` reference and member function; `Caller` can only know about `Intf`s and not `Impl`s.

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

class Intf
{
public:

  virtual void func() = 0;

  typedef void (Intf::*funcPtr)();
};

class Caller
{
public:

  Caller( Intf& f, Intf::funcPtr func ) : f_( f ), func_( func ) {}

  void func() { f_.func(); }

private:

  Intf& f_;
  Intf::funcPtr func_;
};

class Impl : public Intf
{
public:

  Impl()
    : c_ ( *this, &Intf::func )
//    , c2_( *this, static_cast<Intf::funcPtr>(func2) )
  {
  }

  void callCaller() { c_.func(); };

//  void callCaller2() { c2_.func(); };

private:

  void func()
  {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }

  void func2()
  {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }

  Caller c_;
//  Caller c2_;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Impl i;
  i.callCaller();
  return 0;
}
```

An additional question: could someone explain why in `Impl`'s ctor, it is necessary to qualify the pointer to member function `func()` with `Intf::`? I.e. why is this correct...

```
Impl() : c_ ( *this, &Intf::func ) {}
```

...and why are these not correct...

```
Impl() : c_ ( *this, &Impl::func ) {}
Impl() : c_ ( *this, &func ) {}
```

?

The compiler error in the case of the '&Impl::func' version is:

> g++ -g main.cpp && ./a.out

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'Impl::Impl()':
main.cpp:31:31: error: no matching function for call to 'Caller::Caller(Impl&, void (Impl::*)())'
     : c_ ( *this, &Impl::func )
                               ^
main.cpp:31:31: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:16:3: note: Caller::Caller(Intf&, Intf::funcPtr)
   Caller( Intf& f, Intf::funcPtr func ) : f_( f ), func_( func ) {}
   ^
main.cpp:16:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'void (Impl::*)()' to 'Intf::funcPtr {aka void (Intf::*)()}'
main.cpp:12:7: note: Caller::Caller(const Caller&)
 class Caller
       ^
main.cpp:12:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

The compiler error in the case of the '&func' version is:

```
>g++ -g main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In constructor 'Impl::Impl()':
main.cpp:31:20: error: ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&Impl::func' [-fpermissive]
     : c_ ( *this, &func )
                    ^
main.cpp:31:25: error: no matching function for call to 'Caller::Caller(Impl&, void (Impl::*)())'
     : c_ ( *this, &func )
                         ^
main.cpp:31:25: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:16:3: note: Caller::Caller(Intf&, Intf::funcPtr)
   Caller( Intf& f, Intf::funcPtr func ) : f_( f ), func_( func ) {}
   ^
main.cpp:16:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'void (Impl::*)()' to 'Intf::funcPtr {aka void (Intf::*)()}'
main.cpp:12:7: note: Caller::Caller(const Caller&)
 class Caller
       ^
main.cpp:12:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Comment: I recommend you stop using function pointers all together, and instead use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: As for why you get an error, the compiler spells it out quite clearly: "ISO C++ forbids taking the address..." In other words, it's fobidden by the standard.

Comment: Forgot to note: I am limited to C++03; I will update the post.

Comment: @StoneThrow: *Forgot to note: I am limited to C++03;* Simply Wow!

Comment: `void (Intf::*)()` and `void (Impl::*)()` are 2 different types. Not all `Intf` would be `Impl` so generally you cannot call the later with `Intf` instance.

Comment: You first describe a situation that you would like to have, but don't mention concrete problems or error messages. Then as "additional questions" you post concrete errors, where you know a workaround to get back to you original problem. This will probably distract people from the original question, as it's easier to deal with a compiler error then with "It doesn't do what I want". I, for example, don't know what is the concrete problem (i.e. error message) with your intended (and probably tried) implementation using the commented static cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the old way callback:

```
typedef void (*callback_t)(void*);
```

an helper function:

```
template <typename C, void (C::*M)()>
void member_func(void* instance)
{
    C* c = static_cast<C*>(instance); // Not typesafe :-/
    ((*c).*M)();
}
```

And then

```
class Caller
{
public:
    Caller(Intf& f, callback_t func) : instance(f), func_(func) {}

    void func() const { func_(&instance); }
private:
    Intf& instance;
    callback_t func_;
};

class Impl : public Intf
{
public:
    Impl()
      : c_  ( *this, &member_func<Intf, &Intf::func> )
      , c2_ ( *this, &member_func<Impl, &Impl::func2> )
  {
  }
// ...
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58e785a001100c37)

Since C++11, you might replace `Caller` by `std::function<void(void)>` and initialize it by `c2_([=](){ this->func2();})`. and call it `c2_();`